# Select min values for an id and for entire table in ONE query

Tags: sql

I want to find the lowest visited value for a specific id AND the lowest for entire table.
In one query.

**MyTab**

```
ID  VISITED
101 2009
102 2010
103 2011
104 2012
105 2013
```

**Can I do it in one query?**

Right now I do like:

```
select
  min(visited)
from
  mytab
where
  id = 100;
```

and then I do the second query.

```
select
  min(visited)
from
  mytab;
```

**What I want is something like below (but can one make it more simple?)**

```
select 
  min( a.visited ),
  min( b.visited )
from
  (select visited from mytab where id=100) as a,
  (select visited from mytab) as b;
```

---

```
Query run for e.g. id 103 and 100 would be:
id 103 will give 2011,2009
id 100 will give null,2009
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MIN` with `CASE`:

```
select 
    min(case when id = 100 then visited end) minbyid,
    min(visited) minoverall
from mytab
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4fa8b/1)

Answer (score 1):

```
select  min(visited) as GlobalMin
,       min(case when id = 100 then visited end) as MinForId100
from    mytab
```